# Angular NgRx weird behaviour on build mode comparing to dev mode

Tags: angular, ngrx, reactive, ngrx-store

I'm using [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) lib in an Angular 7 project. 
To show a component depending on screens I use store to save a `state`: enabled or disabled. 
It works perfectly on dev mode: `ng serve` but once I generate the project using `ng build --base-href''` I found a different behaviour : some components that aren't meant to be showed are really here ! 
Anyone experienced this behaviour ? found solutions ?

Here is my code :

**Reducer**

```
export function simpleReducer(state: string = 'activated', action: Action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case '1':
      return state = 'activated'

    case '0':
      return state = 'disactivated'

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Header component** : depending on the screen, I show or not the help button using : `*ngIf="isHelpActivated === 'activated'"`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select('message').subscribe(value => {
      this.isHelpActivated = value;
    });
  }
```

**Coordiantes component** : example of screen where I need to show help button

```
export class CoordinatesComponent implements OnInit {
...
  constructor(
    private store: Store<HelpState>,
    ...
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch({type: '1'});
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

**HelpState interface**

```
interface HelpState {
  message: string;
}
```

**AppModule configuration for NgRx**

```
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
...

@NgModule({
...
imports: [
...
StoreModule.forRoot({message: simpleReducer}),
...]
})
```

Comment: can check if the following gives the same result `ng serve --aot`?

Comment: the issue persists .. for information, I am using IE11